# Overriding SaveChanges to Create Copy of Entity for Versioning

Tags: serialization, entity-framework-core, json.net

We have an entity **DataClass** and we want to keep the changes to that entity by creating copies of the object and reference the changed object to parent with **ParentVersionId**.

```
public class DataClass : IVersionedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }

    public int? ParentVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataClass? ParentVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DataClass> ParentVersions { get; set; }
}
```

**SerializeDeserialize** method below is used to create the copy of the objects.

```
public static T SerializeDeserialize<T>(T obj, bool convertComplexProperties = false)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new XXXXDateTimeConverter() } };

    var strSource = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);    
    var destination = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(strSource, settings);
    return destination;
}
```

When we call **SerializeDeserialize** with an parameter object with **DataClass** type, everything works fine. However we want to override **DbContext.SaveChangesAsync** and create copies and add them to context while saving changes.

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    var modifiedEntries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        var clonedEntity = ObjectUtility.SerializeDeserialize(modifiedEntry.Entity) as IVersionedEntity;

        clonedEntity.Id = 0;
        cloned.ParentVersionId = (modifiedEntry.Entity as IVersionedEntity).Id;

        this.Add(clonedEntity);
    }
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Above, **modifiedEntry.Entity** is type of **System.Object** and when **SerializeDeserialize** method is called with it, it returns System.Object (clonedEntity) instead of the real type, which throws exception.

As far as I see, only generic way to add an entity to **DBContext** is **Add** method. Is there any way to solve this issue?

**Update:**

I'm thinking of implementing a **IVersionable** interface on my entity classes:

```
public interface IVersionable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int? ParentVersionId { get; set; }
}
```

and cast the **modifiedEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject()** to that interface, setting the related properties and add to DBContext.

```
private void VersionEntity()
{
    var modifiedEntries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified && VersionedTypes.Contains(e.Entity.GetType()) && e.Entity is IVersionable);

    foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        if (modifiedEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject() is not IVersionable clonedTypedEntity) 
            continue;

        clonedTypedEntity.Id = 0;
        clonedTypedEntity.ParentVersionId = (modifiedEntry.Entity as IVersionable)?.Id;

        Add(clonedTypedEntity);
    }
}
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    VersionEntity();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try instead of `SerializeDeserialize` use `MemberwiseClone()`

Comment: In order to call **MemberwiseClone()** (as it's protected method), I have to cast **modifiedEntry.Entity** to some entity type, which I don't know at design time.

Comment: Show signature of `SerializeDeserialize`. Will help you to call this method correctly.

Comment: Parameters, generic arguments.

Comment: `public static T SerializeDeserialize<T>(T obj, bool convertComplexProperties = false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use reflection to call generic method. I have added additional method `CloneObject` to use it instead of invoking `SerializeDeserialize` directly.

```cs
public static class ObjectUtility
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _serializeDeserialize =
        typeof(ObjectUtility).GetMethod(nameof(SerializeDeserialize));

    public static T SerializeDeserialize<T>(T obj, bool convertComplexProperties = false)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new XXXXDateTimeConverter() } };

        var strSource = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);    
        var destination = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(strSource, settings);
        return destination;
    }

    public static object CloneObject(object obj, bool convertComplexProperties = false)
    {
        var method = _serializeDeserialize.MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());
        return method.Invoke(null, new[] { obj, convertComplexProperties });
    }
}
```

But I also can propose variant without such cloning:

```cs
private void VersionEntity()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified && e.Entity is IVersionable);

    foreach (var modifiedEntry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        var cloned = (IVersionable)Activator.CreateInstance(modifiedEntry.Entity.GetType());
        modifiedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(cloned);

        // rollback
        modifiedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(modifiedEntry.OriginalValues);

        cloned.Id = 0;
        cloned.ParentVersionId = ((IVersionable)(modifiedEntry).Entity).Id;

        Add((object)cloned);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please check the update part that made to question? Would it be a better approach or not ?

Comment: Updated answer with my vision.

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv for your solution